# Selecting Different Airlines for planning a trip to Singapore and Bali

Tags: airlines, singapore

I am from Delhi and I am planning a trip to Singapore and an onward journey to Bali. I just wanted to ask 1 thing - Is it possible that I can take different airline carriers for my onward and return journey. This means that I can take an Airline 'A' for travelling to Singapore (from Delhi), Airline 'B' to travel to Bali (from Singapore), airline 'C' to travel back to Singapore (from Bali) and an Airline 'D' to travel back to Delhi (from Singapore).

Your help shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: if you book each leg of the journey yourself you can book with anyone you like

Comment: Yes, but if you book separate tickets then you have to get additional transit visas since you'll have to clear immigration and reclaim your baggage yourself.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you to book your fights with at least 24h between them. As if you have any problem with a flight, you risk to miss the following one. For instance, Bali airport was closed for a few days (a couple of weeks ago) because of a nearby volcano eruption.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, nothing keeps you from booking every part of your trip separately.

There's a few things to keep in mind though:

- If you travel on separate tickets, your baggage will probably not be checked through. That means you will have to collect your luggage and check it in for the new flight in Singapore. So if you have check-in luggage, you will need to factor in more time for transit. This might especially be an issue if you [need a visa](http://www.ica.gov.sg/services_centre_overview.aspx?pageid=252&secid=165) to enter Singapore. (Which is the case if you are an Indian national)
- Your connection will not be assured. That means if your first flight is delayed and you miss your connection, you will have to pay again for a new onward flight. If you book everything on one ticket, this will usually be the airlines responsibility.
- I have had airlines question me before when buying a one-way ticket to Singapore. They will probably want to see your onward ticket as proof that you have a way of getting out of Singapore again, so be sure to have that ready.

Note the above is only true if you book the legs separately. If you book them together and one of the flights happens to be operated by another airline with a codeshare agreement, then everything should be fine.